# How does `printf()` distinguish between floating point arguments and integer type arguments?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

If I have

```
printf("%f\n", 3);
```

I get

```
3.000000
```

And if I have:

```
printf("%f\n", 3.0);
```

I get the same answer.

But here's the thing, 3 and 3.0 should be completely different, bit wise.

3.0 should be something like `01000000010000000000000000000000` (but double precision because of implicit conversion in vararg functions)
3 should be something like   `00000000000000000000000000000011`

3 must somehow be converted to a float before being displayed.

So my question is, how is this done? Does the compiler cheat somehow? How would I implement this in my own variable args function?

Comment: It doesn't. `printf("%f\n", 3);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What compiler did ou use? Just tried it at https://onlinegdb.com/BymQYx1OG and it outputs 0.00000.  But as said it is undefined behavior - that means the compiler can do what it wants including "cheating" as you put it, but that would be odd (and unhelpful) behaviour for a compiler to "fix" your broken code for you.  Set your compiler wrning level hight.  Some compilers have options to explicitly test format specifiers for standard functions and also to add new functions to the check that use the same format specifiers.

Comment: Which compiler, on which platform, produces `3.000000` for integer `3`?  Since it is a constant, there's an outside chance (not probable, but just about possible) that the compiler evaluates the expression at compile time.  Try using an integer variable instead of a literal and you should get different results.

Comment: "_How would I implement this in my own variable args function?_" : You really do not want to do that!  Instead use your compiler's facilities for validating format specifiers.

Comment: It seems to be a common occurrence for the correct answer to appear in the comments on SO. Thanks! I was using GCC 7 on Linux. I hadn't tried it with another compiler. When I re-implemented printf's %f in XV6, GCC didn't seem to want to cheat anymore :/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the compiler evaluates the expression at compile time, there will be a warning for mismatch between format specifier and constant parameter (I guess).

Answer (score 2):

If your source code contained `printf("%f\n", 3);` and the resulting output was “3”, then what most likely happened was something like:

- There is a floating point 3 somewhere else in your program, such as for an assignment statement like `x = 3.;` or another `printf` call such as `printf("%f\n", 3.0);`.
- In order to work with that 3, the compiler loaded it into a floating-point register. It might have done this for code prior to your `printf` or as preparation for code that is after your `printf`.
- When `printf("%f\n", 3);` was evaluated, that floating-point 3 was in the register where a `double` argument is supposed to be when `printf` was called with a `%f` conversion specifier.
- So, since the register used to pass an argument for `%f` happened to have a floating-point 3 in it, the `printf` used that value and produced a result of “3”.

In other words, your program happened to “work” largely by happenstance, not by design. You did in fact call `printf` incorrectly, and it only produced “3” because unrelated factors happened to work out. If the value in that floating-point register had been 5 or −3.25, then printf would have printed that value instead.

The `printf` routine does not have a way of determining which types of values you passed it. (Good compilers do check the types at compile-time, if the format string is a literal [rather than something computed at run-time]. But that is done by the compiler looking at the source code for the call, not by the `printf` routine itself.)

Answer (score 1):

> How does `printf()` distinguish between floating point arguments and integer type arguments?

`printf()` relies on the calling code to pass objects of the *expected* type per its *format*.

---

`printf()` analyzes the *format string*, which in this case is `"%f\n"`.

The `"%f"` steers code to *expect* that the next parameter is a `double`.

If a `float` is passed, it is converted to a `double` as part of the usual conversion of arguments to the `...` part of a function.

With a `float/double` passed by the calling code, `printf()` will properly  get that data as a `double` and print it. **If the calling code passed some other type, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB)**.  This UB is well explain by [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964294/2410359).

> how is this done? Does the compiler cheat somehow?
>
> How would I implement this in my own variable args function?

The unexpected *undefined behavior* seen by OP is **not certainly reproducible** with user code.